# how to open new view on touch even for uitextfield

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, picker

I am just woundering if it is possible and if so how I could go about loading a new
view when the user touches a uitextfield?

What I am trying to do is load a new view where the user will use a picker to populate the UItextField instead of typing the word.

any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need here is the `inputView` property of `UITextField`. If you set this for a text field, then instead of the usual keyboard, the `inputView` object will pop up. I had created [`this example`](http://pastie.org/1962865) for a related problem which uses a `UIPickerView` as an `inputView` to a `UITextField` object. You can check it to see if it helps.

Comment: Yea nice, I didn't want to go down this route but at the end of the day I think its the more accepted design solution instead of bouncing people around pages.

Thanks will try to implement in my solution now :)